# Gnome not installed/working properly

Tags: gnome, firefox, chromium

I was trying to install few add-ons from Software centre which were gnome based extensions. When I press the install button, it doesn't get installed. So I tried installing from their website on both Chromium as well as Firefox. I thought it would get installed but still the page shows
[Chromium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQXJp.png)

[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zoju8.png)

I tried using Terminal to remove and install it again like twice or thrice, still it isn't working. 
I'm also kind of new to Ubuntu. I don't know how to post system logs or something. Please help me. I'll do the needful.!!!!

Comment: I tried to scavenge help from the net directly, couldn't find anything that helped me!!

Comment: I think that you need to install gnome-shell ...

Comment: Or, if you have installed gnome-shell, be sure to explicitly choose it when logging in. The desktop environment shown in those screenshots is Unity.